# LiveData Two-Way Binding

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, android-databinding, two-way-binding

I am trying to learn data binding, and this what I am not able to figure out.

Inside DetailViewModel.kt

```
private val _event = MutableLiveData<Event>()

init {
    appDatabase.eventDao().getEvent(eventId)
        .map { mapper.map(it) }
        .flowOn(Dispatchers.Default)
        .map { _event.value = it }
        .launchIn(viewModelScope)
}

val event: LiveData<Event>
    get() = _event

val isReminderEnabled = Transformations.map(event) { it.alert != Alert.NEVER }
```

When I access `isReminderEnabled` inside layout xml, it shows are method reference.

```
<com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
    android:id="@+id/switchEnableReminder"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:padding="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:checked="@{viewModel.isReminderEnabled()}"
    app:useMaterialThemeColors="true"
    tools:checked="true" />
```

If I do  `android:checked="@={viewModel.isReminderEnabled()}"` build fails. How do I achieve two-way binding on `isReminderEnabled`? So that when the user toggles the switch I can update database accordingly.

**UPDATE**

I have changed

```
val isReminderEnabled = Transformations.map(event) { it.alert != Alert.NEVER
```

to

```
val reminderEnabled: LiveData<Boolean>
    get() = Transformations.map(event) { it.alert != Alert.NEVER }
```

so now I can do this inside xml

```
 android:checked="@{viewModel.reminderEnabled}"
```

But for two-way binding to work I need `MutableLiveData`. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment on your question so I have to submit this as an answer. Have you added a data object in your layout.xml?

```
<data>
  <variable
    name="viewModel"
    type="com.test.ViewModelClass"/>
</data>
```

Comment: I have this defined inside xml.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MediatorLiveData` instead of `Transformations.map`. If you take a look inside the implementation of the latter, you will see that it is using `MediatorLiveData` with one source (would be your `event`). By implementing it yourself, you are not constrained by the return type `LiveData` of the given method `Transformations.map` and two-way binding can `setValue`.